# Loop with 2 different Indexes in R

Tags: r

I create a list called `list_ok`:

```
 list_ok <- list()
 a=c(1,2,3,4,5)
 b=c(6,7,8,9,10)
 c=c(11,12,13,14,15)
 d=c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
 e=c(21,22,23,24,25)

 list_ok[[1]]=a
 list_ok[[2]]=b
 list_ok[[3]]=c
 list_ok[[4]]=d
 list_ok[[5]]=e
```

I want to recreate the list `list_ok` using this for below. Its weird but this idea I will use to another exercise which is much bigger than this:

```
new_list <- list()

for (i in 1:5) {
  for(k in 1:5) {     
    new_list <- list_ok[[i]][[k]]
  }
}
```

The biggest problem I am facing is to know how to handle with two different index `i` and `k`. How do you handle with this?

Also I have been thinking about `lapply` function but it didnt work.

Any help?

Comment: You might find vector indexing of lists useful -- look into `list_ok[[c(i,k)]]` and `list_ok[c(i,k)]`

Comment: Is it possible in a Loop ??

Comment: What's the problem you're having with your loop? It should work fine, except `k` should loop through `1:5` since each element of `list_ok` only has length 5

Comment: @divibisan I edited k goes to 5. If you run the code you will see the problem. I cant create the same ``list_ok list

Comment: The problem is when `i=1` `k=1`, but when` i=2` `k` has to be equal 1 until the loop complete the `i ` values. After this when `i=1` k should be equal 2 and so on until the loop complete the `i` values. After this` k =3` and so on...

Comment: Ah, I see. You're looping through the loop correctly. The problem is that each time you do so, you get the value of one part of `list_ok` and then overwrite all of `new_list` with is. To see what's happening in the list, you should replace your assignment to `new_list` with a `print(paste(i, k))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're after but instead of nested loops, I'd use `lapply` and `:` here:

```
 lapply(seq(1,21,5), function(x) x:(x+4))
 # alternatively: lapply(seq(1,21,5), seq, length.out=5)

 # or with names:
 setNames(lapply(seq(1,21,5), function(x) x:(x+4)), letters[1:5])

 # output:

$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

$c
[1] 11 12 13 14 15

$d
[1] 16 17 18 19 20

$e
[1] 21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: Thanks @lebatsnok but its not what I want. I want to use `list_ok` I dont want to replicate `list_ok`. For example I could extract only the odd numbers of `list_ok` and put it in `new_list`

Comment: I still don't see what you're after but for extracting odd numbers you can do e.g.: `list_bang <- setNames(lapply(seq(1,21,5), function(x) x:(x+4)), letters[1:5])` ;
`odd <- function(x) x[x%%2==0]`; 
`lapply(list_bang, odd)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, first create an object `new_list` to allocate values, then use `[` and each indices `i` and `k` in `new_list[[i]][k]` to populate `new_list` with those values extracted from `list_ok[[i]][[k]]`

```
new_list <- vector(mode = "list", length=5)

for (i in 1:5) {
  for(k in 1:5) {     
    new_list[[i]][k] <- list_ok[[i]][k]
  }
}

> new_list
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
[1] 11 12 13 14 15

[[4]]
[1] 16 17 18 19 20

[[5]]
[1] 21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: this command: `new_list[[i]][k]`means that inside the loop the`i`index has a "priority" ? So first "i" will finish and then k will take the value 2 and so on??

Comment: It's in the other way around. Priority in loops goes from inside to outside, then first `k` has to finish each round and `i` moves one step-ahead.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem consider upvoting and/or accept it